# Site setting Disapperad from site action

Tags: site, claims-based-auth, site-settings

I tried to change the authentication of one of the site collection to use claim based authentication and I did that through power shell. After I finished, the site settings link disappeared from the site action for Admin user. How can I get it back ? site content only there on site action. I do reset the site form the IIS but with no result.

Note, this site is not allowing some of the users to access it despite they have contribute privilege. Some of them can access the site while others got access denied and they all have the same privilege. For that I tried some of the commands on the power shell to use claim based authentication and it actually used it.

Comment: can you open site settings via URL? directly inserting url to address bar

Comment: URL is */_layouts/settings.aspx

Comment: @Danilo No I cannot , it says Sorry, you don't have access to this page . I send the request and it is successfully sent but to approve it I have to access the site setting. what to do :( please help

Comment: can you open settings directly from server? not from your workstation? like, logging in with system account.

Comment: @Danilo No I cannot. Actually I am accessing it directly from inside the server because it gives me access denied from my workstation. Site action only having : Shared with and site contents options.

Comment: @Danilo i went to " change site collection administrators" in central administration and I change the administrator to my user. I access the site from the server with my user and define the admin as a site collection administrator, then the site setting appear. But the main issue remains, which is accessing the site from my workstation. it says "Let us know why you need access to this site" and when I send the request it gives me error "access denied" .